# Give Custom props to TextInput and use it on event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native and trying event handling and came up with a problem.

Suppose I have a code like this

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.textValues = {a: null, b: null};
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.textValues['a'] = this.props.customProps;
    this.textValues['b'] = event.nativeEvent.text;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          customProps = 'T1'
          onChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
        <TextInput
          customProps = 'T2'
          onChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to access textValues from parent component i.e., Demo as well as customProps from TextInput but

- If I bind this with handleChange then this refrence to Demo class and this.props.customProps gives undefined
- If I do not bind this with handleChange then this.textValues is not defined and this.props.customProps gives perfect value

But I want to acess both textValues of Demo and customProps of TextInput in handleChange function.

Comment: First of all never bind a function directly in render or any of life cycle methods. Do binding always inside constructor and call that reference in render.

Answer (score 1):

```html
class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.textValues = { a: null, b: null };
  }

  handleChange = field => (event) => {
   console.log(field)
    this.textValues[field] = event.nativeEvent.text
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput onChange={this.handleChange('a')} />
        <TextInput onChange={this.handleChange('b')} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Since `TextInput ` is not a component he created there are so such things as the `customPros`. What he's trying to do is identify which textfield is changing and the way to do that is by using this prop `onChange={this.handleChange('a')}`, not sure how much better is could have answered the question.

Comment: Answer  = code to fix the problem  + explanation of the problem

Answer (score 0):

do you want the handleChange function to know which TextInput is called from?

try these codes

```
<TextInput
    customProps = 'T1'
    onChange = {(input)=>{
         this.handleChange("T1", input)
      }}
 />
 <TextInput
      customProps = 'T2'
      onChange = = {(input)=>{
         this.handleChange("T2", input)
      }}
 />
```

and the hanleChange function is

```
 handleChange(inputTag, inputText) {...}
```